# How to use SDWebImage to draw image in cgcontext

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, sdwebimage

I want to use SDWebImage to download a image with url and draw it in UIView(use cgcontext), But When download is complete ,there is nothing happen

```
 func drawImage(){
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    println("drawimageaaaaa")
    imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: drawObj.ctn!)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "defaultphoto")!, completed: { (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, type:SDImageCacheType, url:NSURL!) -> Void in
        println("drawimagebbbb")
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        var cgimg = image!.CGImage;
        var rect = CGRect(x: drawObj.points![0].x,y: drawObj.points![0].y,width: drawObj.currentWidth!,height: drawObj.currentHeight!)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextRotateCTM(context,-CGFloat(Double(drawObj.angle!)*M_PI/180))
        if drawObj.isFlip == true{
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.width/2, rect.height/2)
        }else{
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.width/2, -rect.height/2)
        }
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y)
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, cgimg);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    })
  }


  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
       for drawObj in drawObjs {
          if drawObj.drawPara!.drawType == MouseStatus.attach{
             drawImage(drawObj)
          }
       }
   }
```

now I try to run  drawImage function again (same url) the image appear in the UIView

How to draw it in UIView when drownload complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I get it right you want to draw the SDWebImage when drawRect is called

now the issue is...... drawing must be synchronous. you can't just draw the screen anytime you like :D which is what you are trying and not seeing.

(you need to change the whole 'idea' so that you actually DRAW when asked to (when drawRect is called)

## e.g.

```
func drawImage(drawObj) {
        println("drawimagebbbb")
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        var cgimg = image!.CGImage;
        var rect = CGRect(x: drawObj.points![0].x,y: drawObj.points![0].y,width: drawObj.currentWidth!,height: drawObj.currentHeight!)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextRotateCTM(context,-CGFloat(Double(drawObj.angle!)*M_PI/180))
        if drawObj.isFlip == true{
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.width/2, rect.height/2)
        }else{
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.width/2, -rect.height/2)
        }
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y)
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, cgimg);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context) 
}

func loadImage(drawObj){
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    println("drawimageaaaaa")
    imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: drawObj.ctn!)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "defaultphoto")!, completed: { (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, type:SDImageCacheType, url:NSURL!) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ) {
            drawObj.image = image
            self.setNeedsDisplay() //tell iOS to ready for drawing
        }
    })
```

drawObj.imageViewUsedForLoading = imageView //retain it!
      }

```
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
       for drawObj in drawObjs {
          if drawObj.drawPara!.drawType == MouseStatus.attach{
            if drawObj.image /*you have to manage this somehow*/ {
                drawImage(drawObj)
            }
            else { 
                loadImage(drawObj)
            }
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: block in sd_setImageWithURL is not run too after download @Daij-Djan

Comment: it is run asynchronously though

Comment: I know ,I have wait for three minutes,but when I run it again ,image is appear

Comment: THAT is the issue.. if it was loaded, or not isn't the issue.. though you also should retain the imageView that you are using to load the image because arc frees it and that may stop all loading

Comment: don't get it then - sorry